# FreeBSD 10 boot CD doesn't boot on VirtualBox

Tags: freebsd, virtualbox

I downloaded the FreeBSD 10.0 boot CD ISO (FreeBSD-10.0-RELEASE-ia64-bootonly.iso) and am trying to boot it in VirtualBox for a new FreeBSD installation, without success. On boot I get `FATAL: Could not read from the boot medium! System halted.`

I already tried:

- Downloading the other boot ISOs;
- Use the same ISO on VirtualBox running on Windows and Linux hosts, on different computers.

Here are the configurations I'm using on the VM:

[image: VM configuration]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IA64 architecture is different from AMD64 that is, in fact, implemented in the intel's x86-64 platform.

So you have to download and boot `FreeBSD-10.0-RELEASE-amd64-bootonly.iso`